# FreeRTOS is slow to wake after long processor sleep

Tags: freertos, cortex-m, sleep-mode

*(Cross-posted on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/626927/free-rtos-is-slow-to-wake-after-long-processor-sleep))*

I'm using FreeRTOS in an application which requires the processor to sleep in low power mode for a long time (as long as 12 hours), then wake up in response to an interrupt request. I'm having a problem with the amount of time taken for FreeRTOS to wake up.

Before going to sleep, I disable the scheduler through a call to `vTaskSuspendAll()`.

On waking, I calculate the amount of time that the processor has been asleep, and update FreeRTOS via a call to `vTaskJumpTime()`. I then make a call to `xTaskResumeAll()` to restart the scheduler.

The issue I have is that `xTaskResumeAll()` makes a call to `xTaskIncrementTick()` once for each tick that has been missed while the processor was asleep (recorded through `vTaskJumpTime()`). It takes about 12 seconds to wake after an hour asleep (3,600,000 calls to `xTaskIncrementTick()`).

Much as I'm tempted to modify the FreeRTOS `xTaskIncrementTick()` function, so that it can jump a number of ticks in one call, experience says that I would be smart to look for a standard way first.

Has anyone found another way to implement this behavior which doesn't result in the long wake-up delay?

This is implemented on an Microchip/Atmel SAM4L (Cortex-M4). I use the AST sub system to record the time that the processor is asleep. The sleep is implemented through BPM sub system `bpm_sleep()` in RETENTION mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeRTOS's built in low power support uses [vTaskStepTick()](https://freertos.org/vTaskStepTick.html) to [jump the tick count forward in one go](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/main/tasks.c#L2622). It can do that because it won't calculate a wake time (the time at which it leaves low power mode) past the time it knows a task must unblock because a timeout expired.  If you remain in sleep mode past the time a task should have unblocked because its timeout expired you have an error anyway.  The best place to get FreeRTOS support is it's [dedicated support forum](https://forums.freertos.org).